# State not updated using Redux toolkit with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Using createAsyncThunk and extraReducers, I can get data, but the state isn't updated.
Here's the code

```
// matchMakingSlice.ts
export const getOpenChallenges = createAsyncThunk(
  "openchallenges/get",
  async () => {
    const response = await fetchWrapper<Lobby>("api/p/openchallenges", "GET");
    return response;
  }
);

export const matchMakingSlice = createSlice({
  name: "matchMaking",
  initialState: lobbyState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getOpenChallenges.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default matchMakingSlice.reducer;
```

Here I can see the data in the payload, but when I set the state, it doesn't do what I think it would do... Reduc Chrome Addon shows me an empty state. I get the same result trying to use a selector in a component.

Here more infos:

```
// store.ts
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    matchMaking: mathMakingReducer,
    user: userReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export default store;

// component.ts
const Lobby = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOpenChallenges());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const challenges = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    return state.matchMaking.openChallenges;
  });
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your `lobbyState`? It would probably be an array so you would have to append the data to it.

Comment: It is ab object with properties defined with an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state = action.payload` is never a valid operation in an Immer-powered reducer. Immer works by tracking *mutations* to existing `state`, or letting you *return* a new value. `state =` just changes the local `state` variable to point to something different, which is neither a mutation nor a return.  You need `return action.payload`.

See [the RTK "Writing Reducers with Immer" docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) for further details on this.